# Insert Table Of Contents at the beginning of Word Document

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop, tableofcontents

I have the table of contents code below. I need to put this on the second page of my document. The document is 15 pages long. To insert it on the second page, i will have to add a page break at the end of the 1st page, and then have the table of contents insert on the second page.

How can I put it on the second page of the document? I know its something with range, but I'm note sure how to do that.

The code for the table of contents is below.

```
object oTrueValue = true;
        object start = oWord.ActiveDocument.Content.End - 1;

        Word.Range rangeForTOC = oDoc.Range(ref start, ref oMissing);
        Word.TableOfContents toc = oDoc.TablesOfContents.Add(rangeForTOC, ref oTrueValue, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oTrueValue);
        toc.Update();

        Word.Range rngTOC = toc.Range;
        rngTOC.Font.Size = 12;
        rngTOC.Font.Name = "Arial";
        rngTOC.Font.Bold = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the end of the first page, then add a page break, and then a ToC:

```
// Go to end of document
Object what = WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine;
Object which = WdGoToDirection.wdGoToLast;
wordApp.Selection.GoTo(what, which, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Insert a page break:

```
`selection.TypeText("\f");//page break`
```

Create ToC:

```
selection.Font.Bold = 1;
selection.TypeText("Table of Content\n");
TableOfContents toc = wordDoc.TablesOfContents.Add(selection.Range, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
}//if
```